# Download file from regular site via proxy in C#

Tags: c#, file, proxy

I need to be able to download some file from a regular site using my proxy server.

I already tried this:

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.Proxy = new WebProxy(ip, port);
client.DownloadFile(url);
```

but it's not working at all. What did I miss? Without a proxy, it works.

Comment: *Not works at all* is not a problem description that allows us to help you much. Please give more details: what kind of proxy, does it require authentication, if yes what type? Then describe what happens when you run this code. Are you getting an exception? If yes post the full stack trace, etc... Also formatting your source code helps (Select the code and press CTRL+K in the editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get an error? Do you need to specify some [credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.credentials.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your proxy is dead? Did you checked it? Please provide more information about it, did you get error/exception ?

We can't help you if you don't provide us with information we must know ;)

Comment: This could have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The WebProxy(ip, port) should be WebProxy("yourProxy:port", bool) where bool specifies if local address have be bypassed...

This should make it work